# How to upload files in an Asp.net MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, httppostedfilebase

I'm trying to upload files in my application. I've used `HttpPostedFileBase` in my model and a `byte[]` array but don't know why this error is showing when i'm running my application. Below I've also uploaded the `image` of the error that is showing when running the app.

The error that is showing is:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> AdSite.Models.HttpPostedFileBase: : `EntityType 'HttpPostedFileBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.`
> HttpPostedFileBases: EntityType: EntitySet 'HttpPostedFileBases' is based on type 'HttpPostedFileBase' that has no keys defined.`

[image: Error screenshot]

My Model:

```
public class Album
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
    public int ImageSize { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select image file.")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }        
}
```

My controller code:

```
public ActionResult Upload([Bind(Include = "Id,ProductTitle,Description,ImageFileName,ImageData,File,ImageSize")]Album album)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //  album.ImageFileName = album.File.FileName;
        // album.ImageSize = album.File.ContentLength;

        byte[] data = new byte[album.File.InputStream.Length];
        album.File.InputStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        album.ImageData = data;

        var db = new AlbumContext();
        db.Albums.Add(album);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(album);
}
```

My View code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Select Image:</label> 
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.File, new { type="file"})
        @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the 'Bind' attribute, you define properties for 'album'. Where is the 'File' property coming from?

Comment: Hello @SRQCoder , the `File` property is defined in the `Model class`. it is of type `HttpPostedFileBase  File`. You can see my model class here.

Comment: You need to remove `public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }` from your data model (its a complex object and cannot be stored in a database column). You editing data so use a view model and the view model will contain that property (and not the `public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }` property - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

This is why you want to use Models to retrieve the data and then convert it to your DTO objects.

The error is because you're trying to store the [`System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.110).aspx) class into your database. That's not your class to control, and it wasn't created to be stored directly in a database. In this case, `HttpPostedFileBase` is your "model".

Create another object and tie it into your `DbContext` to store what you need to about the file in your database. Don't just toss the object in there.

Comment: thanks. but can you please show me an example code of this here?

Comment: do you mean to create a new "model class" for other info about the file that need to upload? that is do i need two class, one for HttpPostedFileBase property and one for the other property??

Comment: I meant create a DTO class for whatever info you need from `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Comment: I've provided a link to the `HttpPostedFileBase` class. You already have your `Album` class, just do a similar process for your File.

Comment: @krillgar Could you please help to resolve this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602008/how-to-upload-folder-and-sub-folders-and-files-inside-the-sub-folders-in-asp-net)

Comment: @SafeerMP That question is far too broad. It also may not be possible to upload "everything" do to different levels of Operating System and Browser security.